# How to set up Node.js app on AWS with domain and SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, devops

Excuse me if I'm posting this in the wrong category.

I have a node.js app running on an EC2 instance on port 3000.

What is the best way to set up https with my domain, so that when the user goes to
`https://www.my-domain.com` they're actually hitting `my-ec2-instance.com:3000` ?

I actually ended up putting the client on cloudfront, and cloudfront managed setting up SSL with my domain so when I go to `https://my-domain.com` the client is served just fine, but I cannot make http requests to my server on the EC2 instance because the origin is different. The browser blocks http requests.

I also tried having the node server deliver my client which works, and you can see it here: http://34.223.222.234:3020/

then I set up Route53 to reroute to the IP address, you can see it here:
http://myonlinetesting.com:3020/

But Route53 won't allow me to add the port number as part of the IP to reroute to. And on top of that I still need to set up SSL so the the user can go to https://myonlinetesting.com. And I also need to reroute http traffic to https so the users is always on https.

From your experience, what is the best way to accomplish a web application set up like this? Do you have cloundfront serve your client and host the server on an EC2 instance? Or do you just have a load balancer in the middle so you can accomplish SSL? Seems like a waste of resources this way, when you don't really need a load balancer. Or do you have your app running on the EC2 instance and somehow are able to route traffic to your-ec2-instace.com:3000 when the user goes to `https://yourdomain.com`?

I'm pulling my head in different directions without really knowing what the best way to do this is. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com

    <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Consider the nodejs app is running on port 3000

Answer (score 1):

You can't point a domain name to a specific port. A domain name points to an entire server, not a specific port on that server. The default HTTP port is `80`, and the default HTTPS port is `443`. So if you want users to be able to go to your website without having to specify a port number like `3020` then you need to configure your website to run on the default HTTP/HTTPS ports. Or configure your operating system to forward those default ports to the ports your application is actually running on (for example via `iptables`).

For SSL, since you aren't using a load balancer or a CDN the you will need to install the SSL certificate directly on the server. You can do this for free using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).